# Changing number from character array to int array with decimal value

Tags: c, switch-statement

I am starting to learn C and I am having problem with changing numbers from character array to integer array. Here is my Code and I got random number and I have no idea why I am having those numbers.

The answer is **0 , 45, 45, 45**
and I used 15 for plus sign, 25 for minus, 35 for multiply and 45 for division just for testing.

And also the answer which I want is if `char[]="+123"-> int[0]=15;int[1]=1;int[2]=2;int[3]=3;`

Thanks in advance and very much appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=0;
    char retezec[]="123+";
    int array_length=(sizeof(retezec) / sizeof(retezec[0])-1);
    int new_array[50];
    while(retezec[i++]!='\0'){
        switch(retezec[i]){
            case '0':
                new_array[i]=0;
            case '1':
                new_array[i]=1;
            case '2':
                new_array[i]=2;
            case '3':
                new_array[i]=3;
            case '4':
                new_array[i]=4;
            case '5':
                new_array[i]=5;
            case '6':
                new_array[i]=6;
            case '7':
                new_array[i]=7;
            case '8':
                new_array[i]=8;
            case '9':
                new_array[i]=9;
            case '+':
                new_array[i]=15;
            case '-':
                new_array[i]=25;
            case '*':
                new_array[i]=35;
            case '/':
                new_array[i]=45;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<array_length;i++){
        printf("%d\n",new_array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are incrementing `i` first then using switch. So, the output will be off by 1. Also while not using `array_length` in a for loop, instead of while loop

Comment: Hint: whne you define a local array init it `int new_array[50] =  {0};`

Comment: Could simplify the switch to `case '0': case '1': .... case '9': new_array[i] = retezec[i] = '0'; break;`

Comment: Why the `-1` here: `array_length=(sizeof(retezec) / sizeof(retezec[0])-1);`?

Answer (score 3):

Adding with the previous answers the reason you are getting 45 every time is that you haven't given the **break** keyword in every condition of switch case. Just add it and you will get the desired output :)
For example:

```
case '0':
    new_array[i]=0;
    break;
```

See the link below to have a good understanding. Hope it will help you.
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-switch-case-statement

Answer (score 1):

In your code -

```
while(retezec[i++]!='\0'){
    switch(retezec[i]){
       ....
```

`i` is 0 when while loop condition is first evaluated, but in switch `i` already becomes 1. So your switch block checks elements from index 1 and not 0. Same way `new_array` is populated from index 1. The `new_array[0]` then have garbage value (as you are not initializing `new_array`)

You can use a for loop which will loop until `array_length` instead of the while loop  like -

```
for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    switch(retezec[i]) {
       ....
    }
}
```

Also the switch case looks like an overkill. May be replace it with `if`-`else`

Answer (score 0):

This can be boiled down significantly knowing that the C standard define the binary representation of `0` to `9` to necessarily be continuous.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for calloc() */
#include <stdio.h> /* for fprintf() */

int main(void)
{
  char retezec[] = "123+";
  size_t array_length = sizeof retezec  / sizeof *retezec; /* sizeof evaluates to size_t not int. */
  int * new_array = calloc(array_length * sizeof *new_array); /* Only get as much as needed, and have set to all 0s. */
  if (NULL == new_array)
  {
    perror("calloc() failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (size_t i = 0; retezec[i] != '\0'; ++i) /* Use a for-loop where a for-loop can be used. */
  {
    switch(retezec[i])
    {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            new_array[i] = retezec[i] - '0';
            break;

        case '+':
            new_array[i] = 15;
            break;

        case '-':
            new_array[i] = 25;
            break;

        case '*':
            new_array[i] = 35;
            break;

        case '/':
            new_array[i] = 45;
            break;

        default:
            sprintf(stderr, "Unhandled character: '%c'\n", retezec[i]);
            break;
      }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < array_length; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d\n", new_array[i]);
    }

    free(new_array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
```